# How to reference specific implementations of generic interfaces in XML comments?

Tags: .net, generics, comments

Consider this scenario, 2 interfaces, 1 generic:

```
public IGenericAdder<T>
{
   T Add(T, T);
}

public IIntAdder : IGenericAdder<Int32>
{
}
```

Is there someway that I can do XML comments on the generic add method, so that intellisense will show "Adds the Int32" if I do a:

```
IIntAdder foo;
foo.Add(  //Show intellisense here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way. You could:

- Make the comment generic enough to work (ie. "Adds two items together") and let the user infer the type from the Visual Studio generated docs/tooltip.
- Hide the `T Add(T, T)` method of `IGenericAdder` with `new int Add(int, int)` in `IIntAdder` and put specific XML docs on it that refer to the correct types (ie. "Adds two ints together").
- Use <see cref="T"/> in the XML docs, but Visual Studio just refers to it as `T`.

None of these really do what you originally asked though.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be my conclusion as well :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a doc comment - Visual Studio automatically fills in the generic type argument into the tooltip.

Comment: Ye, but say I want some custom comment in the Add method, but I also want my comment to write "Int" instead of "T" where the generic parameter has been specified