# How Can I add comment for my interface? (XML Documention)

Tags: c#, xml, generics, interface, documentation

I have an interface as below:

```
  public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{  
...
}
```

**Updated**:
most of my entities would implement this interface.  I've become confused in adding xml documentation for s.th. like below (in interface):

```
            /// <summary>
            /// This method returns All What??????
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns> <see cref= "OutputWithPaging{T}"/> </returns>
     OutputWithPaging<T> GetAll();
```

[image: XML Documentation]

which Test implements IBaseRepository. as you see I can see City in return part of comment but not in summary part.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// This method returns All objects of type <see cref="T"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns><see cref= "OutputWithPaging{T}"/></returns>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that is not possible to achieve what you want. In fact, your code documentation should describe what it does in non technical therms. Try to make your comment generic enough.

You can use the `<typeparamref name="T" />` or `<see cref="{T}" />` but visual studio will just refer to it as `T`.

None of these really solve your problem though, I'm sorry.

Related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996664/how-to-reference-specific-implementations-of-generic-interfaces-in-xml-comments).